# Turn a list of tuples into a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

From a list of tuples:

```
list1 = [('t', 2), ('oo', 1)]
```

need a list of dictionaries:

```
dict1 = [{'t':2}, {'oo':1}]
```

Comment: you know if you just wanted it as a whole dictionary (like `{'t':2, 'oo':1}`) then it would just be `dict1 = dict(list1)`

Comment: I'd really like to know two things: What have you tried? And Why do you want a list of single element dictionaries?

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = [('t', 2), ('oo', 1)]

list2 = [{x:y} for x,y in list1]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just do this

```
dict1 = [dict([each]) for each in list1]
```

Answer (score 1):

As always, a good solution using the ever-friendly `map` and `lambda` doesn't hurt:

```
dict1 = list(map(lambda x: dict([x]), list1))
```

Comment: the OP asked for a `list` of `dict`s, not a map

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple using a for loop

```
list1 = [('t', 2), ('oo', 1)]
dict1={}    
for i in list1:
    dict1[i[0]]=i[1]
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked for. OP asked for a list of dictionaries, not a single dictionary.